# Allow user to select only one radio button out of many

Tags: java, android

I want to make user select only one radio button out of many radio buttons. Right now, I am able to select many radio buttons.

Here is my code

```
RadioGroup radioGroup = new RadioGroup(mMain);
    for (int k = 0; k < attr_size; k++) {
        String price = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, AppConstants.DECIMAL_POINTS, Float.parseFloat(attributes.get(k).getAttr_price()));
        String name_price = attributes.get(k).getAttr_name()
                + " (" + mMain.getString(R.string.currency_code)
                + " " + price + ")";

        if (!multiSelect.equals("1")) {
            RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton(mMain);
            radioButton.setText(name_price);
            radioButton.setId(i + 6);
            radioButton.setTextSize(12);
            radioButton.setTag(attributes.get(k));
            radioButton.setGravity(Gravity.START | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
                radioButton.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_VIEW_START);
            }
            setTextFont(radioButton, "Museo_Slab.otf");

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    1f);
            lp.setMargins(10, 10, 0, 10); // llp.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);

            radioButton.setLayoutParams(lp);
            RadioGroup.LayoutParams params = new RadioGroup.LayoutParams(RadioGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RadioGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            attr_layout[i].addView(radioButton, lp);
        }

 }
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: use radio group  https://www.mkyong.com/android/android-radio-buttons-example/

Comment: use RadioGroup.

Comment: RadioButton should be the direct child of RadioGroup

Comment: Can anyone make changes in code?

Comment: radioGroup.addView(radioButton, params); to make like this, i have this part attr_layout[i].addView(radioButton, params);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this in your xml file:

```
<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radiogroup"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" />
```

and do the following:

```
RadioGroup rgp = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radiogroup);
RadioGroup.LayoutParams rprms;

for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton(this);
  radioButton.setText("new" + i);
  radioButton.setId("rbtn" + i);
  rprms = new RadioGroup.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
  rgp.addView(radioButton, rprms);
}
```

Comment: I have attribute[i] here. attr_layout[i].addView(radioButton, params);

Comment: I know I should make it radio group name.. But  if i give like that here, i get erro

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you.

Comment: If u look at my code, hope u will find the above mentioned line.

Comment: I cant set radiogroup.addView(radioButton, params)

Comment: Ok. but first your question was like `radioGroup.addView(radioButton, params); `. let me check

Comment: Did u check? @Shilin

Comment: what is `attr_layout`? can you show some more code?

Comment: why don't you try making the layout in xml and inflating it like this?`LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.my_layout);`

Answer (score -1):

use `RadioGroup` like this :

```
<RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/radio_male"
            android:checked="true" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/radio_female" />

    </RadioGroup>
```

Comment: He is adding his buttons dynamically through code. Not sure how this will help him

Comment: I want to achieve it through programmatically. Can you check the code and make changes?